# Advanced multidimensonal difficulty

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to echo an array out, but I get errors I am not able to figure out.
Tried sereval ways to change the code, and I think my best output so far is:

```
$b  = array(
    array("number 1",   array(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)),
    array("number 2",   array(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)),
    array("number 3",   array(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)),
    array("number 4",   array(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)),
    array("number 5",   array(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)),
    array("number 6",   array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)),
    array("number 7",   array(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)),
    array("number 8",   array(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)),
    array("number 9",   array(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)),
);

for ($row=0; $row < count($b); $row++) { 
    echo "<p><b>Answer : </b>".$b[$row][0]."</p>";
    for ($col=0; $col < 30; $col++) {
        echo "<p>".$b[$row][$col]."</p></br>";
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error:

> number 1 number 1 Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendoTest\test.php on line 62 Array Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendoTest\test.php on line 62

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: What error are you getting? What is your intended output?

Comment: `$col < count($a)` -- where did `$a` suddenly come from? I'd guess you're getting an `undefined variable` error?

Comment: Answer : number 1

number 1


Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendoTest\test.php on line 62
Array

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendoTest\test.php on line 62

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, edited it to 30 instead of count($a) @rickdenhaan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$b  = array(
    array("number 1",   array(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)),
    array("number 2",   array(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)),
    array("number 3",   array(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)),
    array("number 4",   array(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)),
    array("number 5",   array(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)),
    array("number 6",   array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)),
    array("number 7",   array(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)),
    array("number 8",   array(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)),
    array("number 9",   array(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)),
);

foreach ( $b as $answers )
{
    echo "<p><b>Answer : </b>".$answers[0]."</p>";
    foreach ( $answers[1] as $val )
    {
        echo "<p>".$val."</p></br>";
    }
}
```

I believe this is what you want. See [this](https://www.tehplayground.com/X20ecsbB7QOkU7IR) playground for the output.

The main issue with your code stems from this line:

```
echo "<p>".$b[$row][$col]."</p></br>";
```

An example of `$b[$row]` is this:

```
array("number 1",   array(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0))
```

Index 0 is the answer, and Index 1 is the actual array of 0's and 1's. So if you want to loop through that second array, you would need to use `$b[$row][1][$col]`.

Your fixed code:

```
for ($row=0; $row < count($b); $row++) { 
    echo "<p><b>Answer : </b>".$b[$row][0]."</p>";
    for ($col=0; $col < 30; $col++) {
        echo "<p>".$b[$row][1][$col]."</p></br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: That is it! Thanks alot @FrankerZ. Care to explain what I did wrong?

Comment: @tryAnroid Also, check [this playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/xScifId6CHXIzpmS) out. You should just use the answer as the key, and the values as the value for each item. It would be a much easier way of dealing with the array.